# Error while connecting to the server form jaspersoft studio or ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to connect to the server from jaspersoft studio (or ireport) and while doing this I am getting following error message:

```
 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (404)Not Found
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
{}:return code:  404
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;Apache Tomcat/6.0.26 - Error report&lt;/title&gt;&lt;style&gt;&lt;!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--&gt;&lt;/style&gt; &lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;h1&gt;HTTP Status 404 - /jasperserver/services/repository&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;HR size=&quot;1&quot; noshade=&quot;noshade&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;type&lt;/b&gt; Status report&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;message&lt;/b&gt; &lt;u&gt;/jasperserver/services/repository&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;description&lt;/b&gt; &lt;u&gt;The requested resource (/jasperserver/services/repository) is not available.&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;HR size=&quot;1&quot; noshade=&quot;noshade&quot;&gt;&lt;h3&gt;Apache Tomcat/6.0.26&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:404

(404)Not Found
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:221)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.RepositorySoapBindingStub.list(RepositorySoapBindingStub.java:336)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.getVersion(WSClient.java:155)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.getServerInfo(SoapConnection.java:107)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.connect(SoapConnection.java:128)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.connect(ProxyConnection.java:86)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.checkConnection(WSClientHelper.java:82)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard.connect(ServerProfileWizard.java:99)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard.access$1(ServerProfileWizard.java:95)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard$2.run(ServerProfileWizard.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

I clicked on icon for adding server and I gave username and password as "jasperadmin" and clicked on next and after hitting next button its showing me the above message. I am not getting the reason behind this error. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I did silly mistake. In the URL **http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/** I replaced jasperserver with jasperserver-pro So that my URL look like **http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/**. Now its working fine.
I changed URL because I ma using jasperreports-server-4.7 and in that directory name is jasperserver-pro. So I tried with it and its working fine.